# If $x^{1/2}$ is the same as $ \sqrt[2] x$ then why $x^{1/3}$ is not equal to $\sqrt[3] x$?

Tags: square-numbers

If $x^{1/2}$ is the same as $\sqrt[2] x$ than why $x^{1/3}$ is not equal to $\sqrt[3] x$ and $x^{1/4}$ not equal to $\sqrt[4] x$ and so on...?

Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand what you mean. Also, do you mean $\sqrt[2]{x}$, and have difficulty typing it, or really $2 \sqrt{x}$.

Comment: what do these symbols $\sqrt[3] x, x^{1/3}$ mean to you? can you compute some them, at least for some nice values of $x.$

Comment: $x^{1/3}=\sqrt[3]x$ and $x^{1/4}=\sqrt[4]x$ and also $x^{1/n}=\sqrt[n]x$. It would be great to think a little bit before to post as here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126743/why-271-3-sqrt327-3-as-271-3-9-and-sqrt327-3

Answer (score 5):

$x^{1/2}$ is just $\sqrt[2]{x}$ since :

$$
x^{1/2}x^{1/2}=x^{1/2+1/2}=x=\sqrt[2]{x}\sqrt[2]{x}, \tag*{$x\geqslant0$}
$$

hence $x^{1/2}=\sqrt[2]{x}$.

Using the same idea you can show that $x^{1/n}=\sqrt[n]{x}$, for $n=2,3,\ldots$

Comment: I think they meant $x^{1/2}$ is the same as $\sqrt[2]{x}$. And indeed, $x^{1/n}$ is the same as $\sqrt[n]{x}$ for positive integers $n$.

Comment: This http://web2.0calc.com/ and every other calculator tells me that 2√25=5 and √25=5. so there is not a difference. And if x^1/2 is just 2√x then why 25^1/2=12.5 and 2√25=5..?

Comment: Please add that this only works (in a unique way) for non-negative real numbers.

Comment: @Muhammad Asif: When you write 25^1/2 on your calculator it may actually computing, $(25^1)/2=25/2=12.5$.  Try writing 25^(1/2) instead.

Comment: Thanks once again Peder. The way the calculator works was actually confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

It mostly depends on conventions. According to the one I follow, the function $x\mapsto x^{1/3}$ is only defined for $x>0$, because I use the definition
$$
a^b=e^{b\log a}
$$
when $b$ is not integer. Since $\log a$ is defined only for $a>0$, the map $x\mapsto x^{1/3}$ is defined only for $x>0$.

In this way I can say without posing any condition that, for instance,
$$
x^{1/3}=x^{2/6}=(x^2)^{1/6}
$$
which would be utterly false when $x<0$ and I defined $x^{1/3}=\sqrt[3]{x}$.

Other people accept $x^{1/3}$ also for negative $x$, but, in this case, algebraic manipulations like the one above require care.